# TerminateExecution, IsExecutionTerminating, and Clearing V8 Interrupts

Tags: v8

#### the context

The [plv8 javascript language](https://github.com/plv8/plv8) extension for the postgreSQL database uses V8 isolates for computing javascript code as queries.  When plv8-based queries are cancelled, a signal-handling code executes the [`TerminateExecution` method of the isolate](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/api/api.cc;l=8583).  This ultimately raises an interrupt, setting the thread-local `interrupt_flags` for termination.  Presumably, when the isolate resumes execution, the interrupt handler will throw a termination exception. Later, the language extension uses the `IsExecutionTerminating` method to determine if the isolate has received the exception and clears it with `CancelTerminateExecution`.

#### the problem

However, in some cases, the call to `TerminateExecution` was the last interaction with the isolate, before executing a new javascript query.  In this case the isolate is still interrupted, but `IsExecutionTerminating` will return `false` because [that only checks for the exception, *not* the interrupt](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/execution/isolate-inl.h;drc=bead2b4d2553e57229747b48b3dceaadbb8972bf;bpv=1;bpt=1;l=105).  Then, when it begins executing the *next* query, [the interrupt is handled](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/execution/stack-guard.cc;l=267;bpv=1;bpt=1) and the exception is thrown and the current query fails because of the cancellation of the *previous* query.

#### the question

My question for v8 experts is this:  is there any way to effectively clear the interrupts prior to running any js in the isolate?  Alternatively, is there any simple way to trigger the exception being thrown so that it can be cancelled prior to any of the query-based code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried calling `CancelTerminateExecution` unconditionally? That should do the trick.

(If you want, you can also track on your end whether `TerminateExecution` has been called before, but I think CancelTerminateExecution is so cheap that that isn't even worth it.)